# Vlookup first four letters of first and last name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vlookup

I have a list of first and last names in column A and and vlooking it against column B of first and last names.  They all have the same middle name.  There is also a slight variation in spelling of first and last.

I can do exact vlookup but this misses lots of values and `VLOOKUP(LEFT(A3,3)&"*",D$2:D$22,1,FALSE)` gives flat out wrong name.

Is it possible to vlookup first four letters of first and last name so I can match them better or other solution?

```
Column A
Jasondaa J Hoxworth         
Jamiez J Hogabath

Column B    
Jasondaah J Hoxwort
Jamiez J Hogabat

Column C
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,4)&"*",B1:B2000,1,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A3,4)&"*",B1:B2000,1,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as,

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2, 4)&"*"&LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2, " ", REPT(" ", LEN(A2))), LEN(A2))), 4)&"*", B:C, 2, FALSE)
```

I've added to your sample data by mixing up the first and last names while actually returning a value with the VLOOKUP.

[image]